# Html C:Foreach trying to create table with number of ages

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp

I am trying to create a table of users ages if they have a positive test result. Currently I have it working but for every loop it creates another row with the result on. I am trying to have 1 row with the numbers added up. I'm not quite sure how to do this. Below is a picture of the table.

[image]

Below is the code that I have created to get the age and ensure it's between the age brackets.

```
<!-- Infection rate per Age Group -->
 <c:set var="count2" value="0"/>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Under 20</th>
<th>20-29</th>
<th>30-39</th>
<th>40-49</th>
<th>50-59</th>
<th>60-69</th>
<th>Over 70</th>
</tr>
 <c:forEach items="${results}" var="result">
<c:set var="neg" value="Positive"/>
<!-- Set age bounds -->
<c:set var="u20" value="0"/>
<c:set var="b2029" value="0"/>
<c:set var="b3039" value="0"/>
<c:set var="b4049" value="0"/>
<c:set var="b5059" value="0"/>
<c:set var="b6069" value="0"/>
<c:set var="o70" value="0"/>
<c:set var="age" value="${result.age}"/>
<c:set var="pos" value="${result.testResult}"/>

 <c:if test="${neg eq pos}">
<!-- Check if age group is in boundaires -->
<c:if test="${age<20}">
<c:set var="u20" value="${u20 + 1 }"/>
</c:if>

<c:if test="${age >=20}">
    <c:if test="${age <=29 }">
<c:set var="b2029" value="${b2029 + 1 }"/>
</c:if>
 </c:if>
 <c:if test="${age >=30}">
    <c:if test="${age <=39 }">
 <c:set var="b3039" value="${b3039 + 1 }"/>
 </c:if>
</c:if>

<c:if test="${age >=40}">
    <c:if test="${age <49}">
<c:set var="b4049" value="${b4049 + 1 }"/>
</c:if>
</c:if>

 <c:if test="${age >=50}">
    <c:if test="${age <=59 }">
    <c:set var="b5059" value="${b5059 + 1 }"/>
  </c:if>
</c:if>

  <c:if test="${age >=60}">
    <c:if test="${age <69 }">
<c:set var="b6069" value="${b6069 + 1 }"/>
</c:if>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${age >70}">
<c:set var="o70" value="${o70 + 1 }"/>
</c:if>

</c:if>
<tr>
<td>${u20}</td>
<td>${b2029}</td>
<td>${b3039}</td>
<td>${b4049}</td>
<td>${b5059}</td>
<td>${b6069}</td>
<td>${o70}</td>
</tr>

</c:forEach>

</table>
```

So instead of having a row per user (which it is like now) I would just like 1 single row with all ages added up - e.g. the 30-39 category there is 2 positives so this should be 2 rather than 1 and 1. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current code you are setting value of `<c:set..` variable on each iteration i.e : `0` so it will always have value `0` and also your `<tr>` tag is under `c:forEach` so on each iteration new row(tr) is created .Instead you can change you code like below :

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>Under 20</th>
<!--other th-->
</tr>
<!-- put thse varaible outside-->
<c:set var="neg" value="Positive"/>
<c:set var="u20" value="0"/>
<c:set var="b2029" value="0"/>
<c:set var="b3039" value="0"/>
<c:set var="b4049" value="0"/>
<c:set var="b5059" value="0"/>
<c:set var="b6069" value="0"/>
<c:set var="o70" value="0"/>
 <c:forEach items="${results}" var="result">
<c:set var="age" value="${result.age}"/>
<c:set var="pos" value="${result.testResult}"/>

 <c:if test="${neg eq pos}">
<!-- Check if age group is in boundaires -->
<c:if test="${age<20}">
<c:set var="u20" value="${u20 + 1 }"/>
</c:if>

<c:if test="${age >=20}">
    <c:if test="${age <=29 }">
<c:set var="b2029" value="${b2029 + 1 }"/>
</c:if>
 </c:if>
<!--same if statemnts here-->

</c:forEach>
<tr>
<td>${u20}</td>
<td>${b2029}</td>
<td>${b3039}</td>
<td>${b4049}</td>
<td>${b5059}</td>
<td>${b6069}</td>
<td>${o70}</td>
</tr>

</table>
```